# Transition from single node to multi node hadoop same

Tags: linux, node.js, hadoop

I've followed the hadoop single node installation steps from this [link](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/) . And now following this [link](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/) to connect them to make a multi-node cluster. I'm in the beginning of the steps and I just have a question, both my machines have the same username `userA` and they have a second `hduser`. How can I rename `userA` to make it named `master` on one machine and `slave` on the other?

Also I connected them with a wired cable, so they are on the same network, but I wonder how do I do this `configure the network interfaces to use a common network such as 192.168.0.x/24.` as I'm not good in networking.

So if anyone could please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By usernames do you mean users within the machines? Or do you mean server names?
The servers can be named anything you like, and users within the server don't make much difference - just run the installation and configurations by using the same user within one machine. If your master server is called `machineA`, then just use name `machineA` in your configurations instead of `master`.

Also, I recommend to use the newest hadoop version (you didn't specify which version you're using). With the newest version (2.5.1) the linked instructions are not valid - they are for older Hadoop versions. The link's overall picture is good, but for specific instructions I recommend something else, for example http://www.alexjf.net/blog/distributed-systems/hadoop-yarn-installation-definitive-guide/

As for the networking issue, all they need is to be able to SSH to each other without passwords. Doesn't matter where&how they are located.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm a bit confused regarding servers naming. I have two machines were each has two users normal one and hadoop one (userA and hduser respectively) which are exactly the same name on both machines. could you tell me how to set the server names? I think its easy but my mind is a bit mixed up on how to do it :)

Comment: Check command `hostname` for the current name of the server and use that

Comment: Okay i'll give it a go. But if the two machines were setup exactly as the same as single node and have the exact same name, won't hostname give the same result on each machine?

Comment: Well, yes, the names should be different. Unfortunately I can't give you more precise information about how to configure the names - try google for that.